# Error "Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_INVALID_APP, resolution=null}" when using google places api in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places

I am using google maps in my android app and map successfully loaded in my app.
I initialize google map in my app with this code :

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .build();
```

And google places api was worked for me very well, but today an error occurred when using place auto complete!
this is first time that this error is occurred :

```
Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_INVALID_APP, resolution=null}
```

I using the correct api key and all of my code is correct because it worked until today.
But suddenly this error occurred.
Please help me :) thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error indicates something is wrong with you API setup - either the package name or signature is wrong.  If you didn't change your code, the mostly likely thing that is wrong is you signed the app with a different key. If you --

1) Changed from debug to release mode, or

2) Are compiling on a different computer or install of AS in debug mode

Then it is likely that you have to add another SHA-1 fingerprint to your API key.  Follow the instructions on getting your SHA-1 fingerprints here -- https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup.  Check in the API console to make sure you've added all the necessary keys.

Comment: Thanks. your idea worked for me. My problem was that i changed my os and start developing my signed app in new os. So after you help me i useed keytool and signing again in developer console.And now my problem solved

Answer (score 2):

In my case the error was because I put

```
<meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="{MY_KEY}"/>
```

outside **Application** tag. After adding inside **Application** tag all began to work

Answer (score 1):

If you have changed your system after generating the api key then you have to update the current system SHA key in the google api console.

Answer (score 1):

if you have issue on publish app on Google play console.

> Release mangement > app signing > App signing
>   certificate SHA1

Your app public certificate was changed to new one.

Lets check at here first.

Answer (score 0):

If all that is listed here does not help - try set to `no restrictions` in google api console, it helped me